# Docker containers fail to startup > FATA 008 Failed to initialize local MSP

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to launch a network on **hyperledger fabric** which is almost identical to the **'first-network'** fabric-sample. At the point where I start my fabric the dockers (apart from the cli) exit immediately (see image).

[image: docker images]

When I inspect the logs I see that the Orderer fails to initialize local MSP because it cannot load a valid signer certificate (see image).

[image: log]

I tried cleaning the docker images and downloading them again same for the binaries.

[docker-compose-base.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zidb8.png)
[docker-compose-cli.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FsDK.png)

Network composes of:
3 Peers, 1 Orderer and the cli

I would be really thankfull If anyone knows how to deal with this.

EDIT: Solved this issue by resetting docker to factory settings. I assume it had something to do with my docker login credentials.

Comment: how are you generating the required crypto material?  first-network uses cryptogen and mounts volumes from the host which hold the generated crypto material.

Comment: @GariSingh I'm using the cryptogen tool which comes with the binaries downloads.

Comment: Might be a problem that docker cannot access they crypto material

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your compose file for one of your peers and the orderer?

Comment: @GariSingh added 2 snippets in the post

Comment: My best guess is that your containers are unable to mount the volumes from your host system.